# Correct way to calculate Perspective Matrix

Tags: opengl, perspective

I have seen at least 3 different ways to calculate the perspective matrix and I'm confused as to which one I should be using and what the differences are?

OpenGL says to do it this way:

```
f = cotangent(fov * 0.5)

f / aspect, 0, 0, 0
0, f, 0, 0
0, 0, (far + near)/(near - far), (2 * far * near)/(near - far)
0, 0, -1, 0
```

glm does it this way:

```
range = tan(fov * 0.5) * near;  
left = -range * aspect;
right = range * aspect;
bottom = -range;
top = range;

(2 * near) / (right - left), 0, 0, 0
0, (2 * near) / (top - bottom), 0, 0
0, 0, (far + near) / (far - near), -1
0, 0, (2 * far * near) / (far - near), 0
```

Comment: What makes you think that those are any different mathematically?

Comment: When I implement them the OpenGL one seems to make stuff further away?